# corona iOS and Android error while building

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk

all at once today I could not build app neither iOS nor Android. I developed by using Corona Sdk 2014.2511. For both platform I get "Runtime Error":

iOS:
module Facebook not found: resource (facebook.lu) does not exist in archive
no field package.preload["Facebook"]
no file "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/...and so on

Android
/Users/jenkins/slaveroot/workspace/label/android/platform/resources/init.lua:820module "Facebook" not found. resource (Facebook.lu) does not exist in archive
no field package preload...etc

Apparently bot errors depend on Module Facebook! I really don't know what to do. Just followed suggestions from the web and modified file build.settings as follows:

```
settings =
{

orientation =
{
    -- Supported values for orientation:
    -- portrait, portraitUpsideDown, landscapeLeft, landscapeRight

    default = "portrait",
    supported = { "portrait", }
},

excludeFiles =
{
    -- Include only the necessary icon files on each platform
    iphone = { "Icon-*dpi.png", },
    android = { "Icon.png", "Icon-Small-*.png", "Icon*@2x.png", },
},

plugins =
{
    ["CoronaProvider.native.popup.social"] =
    {
        publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
    },
},

{
    ["facebook"] =
    {
        publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
    },
},

--
-- iOS Section
--




iphone =
{
    plist =
    {
        UIStatusBarHidden = false,
        UIPrerenderedIcon = true, -- set to false for "shine" overlay
        --UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = true, -- uncomment to quit app on suspend
        UIAppFonts = { "RepriseStamp.ttf", "REPRISESTAMP.dfont"},
        CFBundleIconFiles =
        {
            "Icon.png",
            "Icon@2x.png",
            "Icon-60.png",
            "Icon-60@2x.png",
            "Icon-60@3x.png",
            "Icon-72.png",
            "Icon-72@2x.png",
            "Icon-76.png",
            "Icon-76@2x.png",
            "Icon-Small.png",
            "Icon-Small@2x.png",
            "Icon-Small@3x.png",
            "Icon-Small-40.png",
            "Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
            "Icon-Small-50.png",
            "Icon-Small-50@2x.png",
        },

        {
        UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false,
        FacebookAppID = "5XXXXXXXXXX",  --replace XXXXXXXXXX with your Facebook App ID
        CFBundleURLTypes =
        {
            { CFBundleURLSchemes = { "fb5XXXXXXXXXX", } }  --replace XXXXXXXXXX with your Facebook App ID
        },

        ["URL types"] =
        {
            item =
            {
                ["URL Schemes"] = { ["Item 0"] = "fb5XXXXXXXXXX" },  --replace XXXXXXXXXX with your Facebook App ID
            },
        },

        }



    }
},

--
-- Android Section
--
android =
{
    usesPermissions =
    {
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
    },
},
}
```

Unfortunately nothing changed. I have been getting always the same errors. Any help? thanks a lot! Ubaldo

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your build.settings.

```
plugins =
{
    ["CoronaProvider.native.popup.social"] =
    {
        publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
    },
    ["facebook"] =
    {
        publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
    },
},
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me and gives me the error. Module 'facebook' not found.